# How to make links in rails hashed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, deep-linking

in my rails app I'm using jQuery BBQ for hashchange deeplinking etc...

Here are my existing links in rails:

```
<%= link_to('View on Site ', project_topic_url(@project.id, @topic, :only_path => false),) %>
```

I have this working in a user_mailer that gets emailed out...

problem is this generated: http://www.site.com/project/1/topic/23

And What I want is: http://www.site.com/#/project/1/topic/23

Any ideas on how I can get the hash #  in the url to be ajax, deeplinking friendly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could always create a helper method to handle this for you.

```
def project_topic_ajax(id, topic)
   "http://www.site.com/#/project/#{id}/#{topic.name}/#{topic.id}"
end
```

Then just call that instead of the default link helper.

**Update**: I found a solution for you.

```
<%= link_to "View on Site", "##{project_topic_url(@project.id, @topic)}" %>
```

It's cleaner, but not exactly what you were looking for I realize.

For absolute paths, it would look like this (a bit dirtier):

```
<%= link_to "View on Site", "http://www.site.com/##{project_topic_url(@project.id, @topic)}" %>
```

Comment: I could, just hoping there was perhaps a setting? I'd imagine this being a pretty common requirement?

Comment: There's the `:anchor` tag which automatically adds a `#` to the end of your path. Other than that, I don't know of any configuration options or helpers that could help you achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks Chuck but the anchor tag is different as you mention

Comment: Hmm, no go. That outputs: <a href="#http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/136/topics/269">View on Site</a>

Comment: Try setting the `:only_path` tag to true (or remove it, as that's the behavior by default). Is there any reason why you need the full path for these links?

Comment: @Chuck, ya I do need the full path as these are links inside of a user_mailer template being emailed out.

Comment: I modified the answer to reflect that. It's the cleanest way I can think of to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'View on Site ', [project_topic_url(@project.id, @topic).gsub(/#{project_topic_path(@project.id, @topic)}/, ""), project_topic_path(@project.id, @topic)].joins("#") %>
```

And you'd better to wrap it as a helper

Answer (score 0):

bit late perhaps; but you could pack your entire routes file in a hash scope like so:

```
MyRails::Application.routes.draw do
  scope :hash, :path => "/#" do
    resources :project do
      resources :topic
      # ...
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

With Rails 3.2.8, running `rake routes` it yielded the desired results.

Not sure how this would affect your views or jQuery-BBQ for that matter